# Facebook PHP API login window popup

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication, sdk

I'm using using the most recent version of facebook's php api sdk.  I'm trying to make the login button activate a popup instead of opening the full page.  I tried using this tutorial: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/create-facebook-popup-authentication-window-using-php-and-javascript/

The popup worked but when I logged in, instead of the popup window closing, the website just opened inside the popup.

Does anybody know what I need to do to make the popup window close once I have logged in?

Here is my php code for generating the login url:

```
<?php
    $loginUrl = $me_on_facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'display' => 'popup',
        'next' => $config['baseurl'],
        'redirect_uri' => $config['baseurl'],
        'scope' => 'email'
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the popup login box loads and the user signs in/connects, the box then loads the site with ?code=XXX appended to the url.  So for the site I added a php if statement

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['state']) && isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        echo "<script>
            window.close();
    window.opener.location.reload();
        </script>";
} else {
        // load page
    }
?>
```

What this does is close the popup and reload the original page that initiated the popup.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Facebook Javascript SDK and authorize user using Javascript function FB.login(). Tutorial is here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: My whole site is based on facebook's php sdk.  Wouldn't initializing the login via javascript sdk affect this?

Comment: When you use Javascript SDK, you make init() with cookie:true parameter. So, Javascript SDK saves token in a cookie, and your PHP SDK then works with that cookie. Init() is described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ - so, Javascript and PHP SDK can both work on same site, and they will share same session using cookie.